# Mirrored pose keys have weird rotations

Tags: animation, armature, pose-mode

I'm trying to complete a basic walk cycle, but I'm having issues using Blender's copy pose/flip pose across the X axis with an armature. The flipped pasted pose is copied (horizontally), but the rotations are screwed up.

I've copied the pose, pasted it and checked flipped X axis, but the rotations come out weird. What is wrong here? I can't find any other easy way to simply mirror a pose. (i.e. for a walk cycle)